# How can I iterate over some file names returned from ls command?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hello I am trying to write a simple bash script,

the problem I am having is that I want to iterate through the 4th,5th,6th and the 7th files returned from the ls command and then to check if these files have write or read permissions and if they do so, to do a simple copy of these files to another directory. What I've done so far is to check if they have the permissions needed and then if they do, to copy them to the `/tmp` directory.
My solution:

`#!/bin/sh`

`for f in *`

`do`

`if [ -w "$f" ] || [ -r "$f" ]; then`

`cp $f /tmp`

`fi`

`done`

The way to get the 4th to 7th file names is through `ls | head -7 | tail -4`,  but how can I iterate specifically though these files names only? Basically how can I make it so the `*` list in the for loop can be these 4 file names?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add an incrementing counter variable to the loop you already have and then add an if statement against the incrementing counter variable.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: “how can I make it so the * list in the for loop can be these 4 file names?”

      for f in $(ls | head -7 | tail -4)

Comment: @HeyYoubooo : Since processing the output of `ls` is discouraged, I suggest that you go through all files in the loop, and reject the ones you don't need. My guess is that will be even faster, since you don't need the three child processes for ls, head and tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not try to parse the output of `ls`. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Using globbing, store filenames into an array and iterate through indices from 3 to 6 (both inclusive). Notice that array indices begin from zero in `bash`. For example, using a C style `for` loop

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(*)
for ((i = 3; i <= 6; ++i)); do
    if [[ -r ${files[i]} || -w ${files[i]} ]]; then
        cp "${files[i]}" /tmp
    fi
done
```

or using a traditional `for` loop with array slices:

```
files=(*)
for file in "${files[@]:3:4}"; do
    if [[ -r $file || -w $file ]]; then
        cp "$file" /tmp
    fi
done
```

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments,  a counter can be implemented to skip the first 3 files and break the loop after the 7th iteration, without resorting to an array:

```
itr=0 # iteration count
for file in *; do
    ((++itr < 4)) && continue
    ((itr > 7)) && break
    [[ -r $file || -w $file ]] && cp "$file" /tmp
done
```

Comment: Even without arrays or the C-style for loop, you can implement a counter to skip the first 3  iterations of `for f in *` and to break the loop after the 7th iteration.

Comment: @chepner Yes, and at first I thought implementing this as you described. I believe the array method is simpler.

Comment: @chepner Anyway, I added this method too, as an alternative to using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If this `ls | head -7 | tail -4` works :

then iterate by ls command result:

```
ls | head -7 | tail -4 | while read line
do

if [ -w "$line" ] || [ -r "$line" ]; then

cp $line /tmp

fi

done
```